# Java allocation of objects within generic functions workaround?

Tags: java

basically what I'm trying to do is allocate a parametrized type from a generic function:

```
public < T > T wishful_thinking(  )
{
    return new T( );
}
```

Casting doesn't work either, due to "object slicing" (that is, it compiles, but "segfaults"):

```
public < T > T wishful_thinking(  )
{
    return ( T )new Object( );
}
```

So...is there any workaround for this (perhaps using reflection or some such)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean it throws a ClassCastError which is very different to a SEG fault.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Yes, I was just using a common programming venacular (hence the quotation marks).

Comment: BTW You can get SEG faults in the JVM, but only with a very low level crash.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. The solution is to pass a `Class` object in your method and use reflection to create an instance.

Example without any exception handling:

```
public <T> T wishful_thinking(Class<T> clazz)
{
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Grrr...there has got to be some way to do this. It's funny really, Java Generics is a compile-time (as opposed to run-time) facility, and yet it doesn't even account for such a basic operation!

Comment: Enums/EnumSets are interesting because they're one of the few java standard classes that run into this problem.

Comment: @SeaBass If the caller can't allocate it, then there is no way a function lower in the call hierarchy could possibly manage it.  For instance, if the caller passed an abstract class or interface.

Answer (score 3):

Generics are not reified in Java. Thus, you can't have something like `new T()`, since T is erased.

The only way to get an object is using `Class` representation :

```
public <T> T wishful_thinking( Class<T> classToInstanciate ) throws ...
{
   return classToInstanciate.newInstance();
}
```